# Installing python packages in Serverless Dataproc GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, dataproc, google-cloud-dataproc-serverless

I wanted to install some python packages (eg: python-json-logger) on Serverless Dataproc. Is there a way to do an initialization action to install python packages in serverless dataproc? Please let me know.

Comment: The official documentation is not helpful: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/python-configuration?

Comment: Yeah, and this documentation is not for serverless dataproc.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. I guess one way would be to create a docker image with the deps baked in, but surely there's a better way.

Comment: I guess this is one possible solution to create a custom docker image: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/guides/custom-containers?hl=en#example_custom_container_image_build

Comment: This blog post was really useful to me.
https://medium.com/cts-technologies/running-pyspark-jobs-on-google-cloud-using-serverless-dataproc-f16cef5ec6b9

Answer (score 3):

***You have two options:***

1. **Using command gcloud in terminal:**

You can create a custom image with dependencies(python packages) in the GCR(Google Container Registry GCP) and add uri as parameter in the command below: 
e.g.

> $ gcloud beta dataproc batches submit 
> **--container-image=gcr.io/my-project-id/my-image:1.0.1** 
> --project=my-project-id --region=us-central1 
> --jars=file:///usr/lib/spark/external/spark-avro.jar 
> --subnet=projects/my-project-id/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/my-
> subnet-name

To create custom container image for [Dataproc Serveless for Spark](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/guides/custom-containers).

2. **Using operator DataprocCreateBatchOperator of airflow:**

Add to python-file the script below, it will install the desired package and then load this package into the container path (dataproc servless), this file must be saved in a bucket, this uses the secret manager package as an example.

*python-file.py*

> ```
> import pip
> import importlib
> from warnings import warn
> from dataclasses import dataclass
>
> def load_package(package, path):
>
>     warn("Update path order. Watch out for importing errors!")
>     if path not in sys.path:
>         sys.path.insert(0,path)
>
>     module = importlib.import_module(package)
>     return importlib.reload(module)
>
> @dataclass
> class PackageInfo:
>     import_path: str
>     pip_id: str
>
> packages = [PackageInfo("google.cloud.secretmanager","google-cloud-secret-manager==2.4.0")]
> path = '/tmp/python_packages'
> pip.main(['install', '-t', path, *[package.pip_id for package in packages]])
>
> for package in packages:
>     load_package(package.import_path, path=path)      
>
> ...
> ```

*finally the perator calls the python-file.py*

> create_batch = DataprocCreateBatchOperator(
> task_id="batch_create",
> batch={
> "pyspark_batch": {
> "main_python_file_uri": "gs://bucket-name/python-file.py",
> "args": [
> "value1",
> "value2"
> ],
> "jar_file_uris": "gs://bucket-name/jar-file.jar",
> },
> "environment_config": {
> "execution_config": {
> "subnetwork_uri": "projects/my-project-id/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/my-subnet-name"
> },
> },
> },
> batch_id="batch-create",
> )

Comment: The first one is what Google recommends. The second suggestion only installs the dependency on the driver. There has to be an easier way to do it rather than having to create a custom image that expires in 60 days.

Comment: @dvarelas when you say that image expires after 60 days, i believe you mean a regular, dataproc image (which is a compute disk image). For dataproc serverless, gcr docker images are used, which do not expire.

Comment: How do you pass the container image to DataprocCreateBatchOperator? @dvarelas